# mutating the linq query to return the desired results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on a `ASP .NET MVC 5` web application and Trying to implement search functionality. I have got `Renders` Entity that has about 14 attributes that are either `many-to-many` or `one-to-one` relations. The user select the attributes using the check boxes so my code is like:

```
if (Request.QueryString["attr1"] != "")
{
    // linq query that gets all the render according to the request
    // to the database that gets converted to t-sql
}
```

I have several `if` statements like the above one in the code now I have modified my code like this:

```
var loadedRenders = _db.Renders.Include(r => r.Images)
                    .Include(m => m.DisplayFormats)
                    .Include(m => m.DisplayMethods)
                    .Include(m => m.DominantColors)
                    .Include(m => m.DrapeTypes)
                    .Include(m => m.CeilingHeights)
                    .Include(m => m.RiggingTypes)
                    .Include(m => m.HardSets)
                    .Include(m => m.SoftSets)
                    .Include(m => m.BackDrops)
                    .Include(m => m.SeatingTypes)
                    .Include(m => m.StageTypes)
                    .Include(m => m.VenueType)
                    .Include(m => m.EventTypes)
                    .ToList();
if (Request.QueryString["attr1"] != "")
{
    // query that filters the renders in loadedRenders using
    // linq
}
```

**Query 1:**

```
renders = renders.Union(loadedRenders
                        Where(r => term != null && (r.Title.Contains(term) || r.ClientName.Contains(term) || r.JobId == (term) && r.ActivateRender))).ToList();
```

**Query 2:**

```
renders = renders.Union(_db.Renders.Include(r => r.Images)
                    .Include(m => m.DisplayFormats)
                    .Include(m => m.DisplayMethods)
                    .Include(m => m.DominantColors)
                    .Include(m => m.DrapeTypes)
                    .Include(m => m.CeilingHeights)
                    .Include(m => m.RiggingTypes)
                    .Include(m => m.HardSets)
                    .Include(m => m.SoftSets)
                    .Include(m => m.BackDrops)
                    .Include(m => m.SeatingTypes)
                    .Include(m => m.StageTypes)
                    .Include(m => m.VenueType)
                    .Include(m => m.EventTypes)
                    .Where(r => term != null && (r.Title.Contains(term) || r.ClientName.Contains(term) || r.JobId == (term) && r.ActivateRender))).ToList();
```

**Question:**

Both queries are returning different results, the reason I think is because one of them is executed in `T-SQL` and on of them in `Linq`, I don't know if I am right but what I want to ask is that is there any way that I can make `Query 1` to return the same result as `Query 2`?

Answer (score 0):

In Query1 you have used loadrenderes which have the below condition

```
.Where(r => r.ActivateRender == true)
```

Whereas in query2 you dont have that conditions which may result in difference

Comment: that does not make any difference since both of my queries have that condition... check the edit

Comment: Check the edit, I removed it from the loadedRenders, I think the difference is because of the `Contains`... Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this line makes the difference

```
.Where(r => r.ActivateRender == true)
```

It exists in assignment to `loadedRenders` but not in Query2

The condition exists also in the query, but applies only to the last option because of [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

If you put all the `a||b||c||...` in parenthesis, and then add `&& r.ActivateRender` - that should help

Answer (score 0):

Change the line in query 2

```
.Where(r => term != null && (r.Title.Contains(term) || r.ClientName.Contains(term) || r.JobId == (term) && r.ActivateRender))).ToList();
```

to this:

```
.Where(r => term != null && (r.Title.Contains(term) || r.ClientName.Contains(term) || r.JobId == (term)) && r.ActivateRender)).ToList();
```

The notable change is moving the condition `r.ActivateRender` out of the paranthesis of the OR conditions.

Comment: Why do I need to check for this condition two times ? `r.ClientName.Contains(term)`

Comment: ah mistake when copying.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the filtering in memory instead of executing the query with the ToList() call.

```
var loadedRenders = _db.Renders.Include(r => r.Images)
                    .Include(m => m.DisplayFormats)
                    ...
                    .Include(m => m.EventTypes)
                    .AsQueryable(); // AsQueryable does not execute the query to sql as ToList would

if (Request.QueryString["attr1"] != "")
{
    // Where() will return IQueryable and the query will not be executed yet
    loadedRenders = loadedRenders.Where(<apply filtering here for attr1>);
}

if (Request.QueryString["attr2"] != "")
{
    loadedRenders = loadedRenders.Where(<apply filtering here for attr2>);
}

// This will then create sql with all the applied filters
var concreteList = loadedRenders.ToList();
```

Comment: but I have got two kind of functions going on one that is using the `union` as you can see above and the other one is without the `union` so its increasing the count at first and then decreasing the count based on the request. Do you think your approach will work in this scenario?

Comment: You can use predicatebuilder http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx to get the Or effect instead of Where, so you don't have to use Union.

Comment: because I need to build up the search according to some attributes and build down the search according to some attributes, this may not make sense but this is what the client wants hence the union...